# test-output folder is not created when i execute maven project in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng

I have selenium project created using Maven. I have included surefire plugin also . When i execute the "mvn test" command using jenkins . I am not able to see the test-output folder . Could you please help me to fix it

Comment: did u check first on local does it create ? and use mvn clean install test

Comment: when i use mvn clean install test surefire report is creating in locally but it is not creating testng default report

Answer (score 1):

TestNG would create the output folder as `test-output` only when running it via the IDE such as eclipse or IntelliJ.

When you run TestNG tests via Maven using surefire plugin, then the output folder is controlled by surefire plugin which is passed on to TestNG as part of the initialization.

By default surefire reports are available under `target/surefire-reports` folder where `target` folder is the default build output folder.

You can customize or change this folder value via https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory

Comment: Hi Krishnan , Thanks for the reply. The actual issue was I have set the below property under surefire report in POM XML.  When we use the below property it will not generate the  testng report after removing the below property value, the testng report is creating successfully <property>
       <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
       <value>false</value> <!-- disabling default listeners is optional -->
      </property>

Answer (score 0):

After executing test script then
Right click on your project folder into eclipse and click on refresh 
button. test-output folder will appear in TestNG

Answer (score 0):

Go to pom.xml file--> right click on pom.xml file --> click on Run As --> click on - 3 maven clean
Done
check Maven project folder test-output folder Added